# WIX and removing .InstallState file

Tags: wix, uninstallation

I have written my first setup program using WIX (version 3.6). When uninstalling the application, an .InstallState file gets left behind in the app folder. Is this supposed to be removed, and if so, what do I need to add to my script to remove it?

I've searched extensively but haven't really come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this file is installed with your application, it should be removed automatically on uninstall.
If this file is created later, then you should add [`RemoveFile`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_removefile.htm) element with `On="uninstall"` into a corresponding component.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But do you know why I should have to add this explicit step to my script? I would think it would just be removed with all other files during the uninstall.

Comment: Windows Installer removes only the files it installed. Other placed in the installation folder treated as user data or configuration. That way if your application creates new files in its installation folders, they have to be explicitly removed.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am not installing this file. Why should I need to explicitly remove it?

Comment: Because you are not installing it.

Comment: I do not know what this file is, what created it, and what is stored in it. So it's up to you to decide whether you remove it or not.

Comment: I don't, either. I mean, I know it is used by Windows Installer, but I don't understand why my WIX script started causing it to be installed, and without correspondingly removing it. I don't have a <Component> entry for this file. But, I just added <RemoveFile> under the <Component> for the main .exe, and it appears to get cleaned up. That will have to do for now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can try running your installation with verbose logging to see what components causes this file to appear. Does it always appear when you install the application? Windows Installer does not create temporary files in installation directories, I guess this file might have been created by a custom action you use.

Comment: I imagine it is installed because I added a user interface action, this is one of the WIX extensions. I would have thought it would have taken care of itself, but it didn't. I do plan on digging deeper into this later - I don't like loose ends. But at least for now I have a workround. Thanks.

Comment: In my experience, an InstallState file is created when you run `InstallUtil.exe yourAssembly.dll`, and your assembly contains an Installer class. It should be perfectly safe if you run `InstallUtil /u yourAssembly.dll` and you remove the file after that.